# How to disable opening app when user tap push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to keep the app from opening when user taps a push notification.
How can I do this?

Here's what I have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (notification != NULL){
            // write code something like doesn't open app.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not possible.We get control at our side after launching the app.

Answer (score 7):

@dheeraj-kumar is right.

1. You can't prevent the app from opening, it's up to the OS
2. Trying to prevent an app from opening is ***almost certainly*** against Apple guidelines and is very likely to result in your app getting rejected
3. Why would you want to prevent a user from opening your app through a push notification? The reason you sent them the notification to begin with was so they know they need to check something in the app, isn't it?