# Tap apple watch push notification issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos

I have an apple watch app that is not independent from the iPhone and I receive push notifications successfully on my watch.

However, tapping the push notification always opens the watch app.  I do not want to handle this in the watch app.  Is there a way to do this?  Is there a way to not open the watch app on tap?

I've tried using the `handleAction()` functions in the  `WKExtensionDelegate` but these are apparently now deprecated, and they never get fired.

Comment: What are you hoping to have happen if the user taps a notification on their watch?

Comment: Re `handleAction()`, did you take a look at `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`, as the deprecation notice in the docs suggests?

Comment: @asyncawait I just want it to dismiss the notification and not open the watch app

Comment: i tried setting up `override func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification, withCompletion completionHandler: @escaping (WKUserNotificationInterfaceType) -> Void)` but it never gets fired

Comment: Do you have the code of producing the notification?thanks

Comment: @Josh O'Connor How to register push notification in Apple Watch

Answer (score 0):

This might not be possible. It relies on the OS.

Possible reasons for this is notifications are *for* the user to click and open the app usually. And this might go against apple app guidelines too to prevent the app from opening.

However, you *can* try these:

This is an example of a foreground service with the notification.

```
public class UploadService extends IntentService{
 
    private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
 
    public UploadService() {
        super("UploadService");
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(this, CancelUploadReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentCancel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, deleteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 
        //building the notification
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_upload)
        .setContentTitle("Uploading Media...")
        .setTicker("Starting uploads")
        .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel, "Cancel Upload", pendingIntentCancel);
 
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        mBuilder.setProgress(100, 0, true);
 
        startForeground(12345, mBuilder.build());
 
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
 
    }
 
}
```

You need to register the CancelUploadReceiver in the manifest file.

```
<receiver android:name=".CancelUploadReceiver"/>
```

And when the “Cancel Upload” is tapped it will receive the broadcast. Then we can simply stop the service.

```
public class CancelUploadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
 
@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   Intent service = new Intent();
   service.setComponent(new ComponentName(context,UploadService.class));
   context.stopService(service);
 }
 
}
```

Another option might be to create a [Custom Interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ModifyingNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH16-SW1) that implements the [UINotificationContentExtension protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension).

Related:

- [Can you disable App-opening mechanism when the user presses the Notification Banner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61345205/can-you-disable-app-opening-mechanism-when-the-user-presses-the-notification-ban)
- [How to disable opening app when user tap push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925303/how-to-disable-opening-app-when-user-tap-push-notification)
- [iOS notifications actions without opening the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214993/ios-notifications-actions-without-opening-the-app)
- [Is it possible to avoid showing app to user when tapping on a push notification in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225862/is-it-possible-to-avoid-showing-app-to-user-when-tapping-on-a-push-notification)
- [Android notifications actions without opening the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392012/android-notifications-actions-without-opening-the-app)
- [Andriod notifications with actions](https://shashikawlp.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/android-jelly-bean-notifications-with-actions/)

Comment: the code you provided looks like Java, however this issue is an Apple Watch issue...